# How to do Nant build using jenkinsfile for a pipeline job in Windows?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, nant

I am changing my Freestyle Jenkins job configuration to Pipeline. I need to Invoke Nant to build a .net application. How is it performed using jenkins file?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in groovy script you can use `bat` function to execute cmd command. So you can type something like `bat '<path_to_nant> <nant_parameters>'`